# Something is killing my wired network, what that could be?

Tags: networking, fedora

I am using Fedora 26 x64 and for some reason - and randomly - the wired network is being killed by something. I did know because I am seeing the message saying the wired network does not exists anymore and I am seeing how WiFi is getting auto-connect. I have tried to restart the service by running:

```
$ sudo service network restart 
[sudo] password for rperez: 
Restarting network (via systemctl):  Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status network.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

But as you can see it fails. The logs from `journalctl -xe` show the following:

```
$ journalctl -xe
-- Subject: Unit fprintd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit fprintd.service has begun starting up.
Nov 14 13:14:39 laptop-mmi dbus-daemon[829]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Nov 14 13:14:39 laptop-mmi audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=fprintd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Nov 14 13:14:39 laptop-mmi systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit fprintd.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit fprintd.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Nov 14 13:14:42 laptop-mmi audit[8060]: USER_AUTH pid=8060 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=3 msg='op=PAM:authentication grantors=pam_unix acct="rperez" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=succes
Nov 14 13:14:42 laptop-mmi audit[8060]: USER_ACCT pid=8060 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=3 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="rperez" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 
Nov 14 13:14:42 laptop-mmi audit[8060]: USER_CMD pid=8060 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=3 msg='cwd="/home/rperez/sources/mmi" cmd=73657276696365206E6574776F726B2072657374617274 terminal=pts/0 res=success'
Nov 14 13:14:42 laptop-mmi sudo[8060]:   rperez : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/rperez/sources/mmi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/service network restart
Nov 14 13:14:42 laptop-mmi audit[8060]: CRED_REFR pid=8060 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=3 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
Nov 14 13:14:42 laptop-mmi sudo[8060]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already occupied by a session
Nov 14 13:14:42 laptop-mmi audit[8060]: USER_START pid=8060 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=3 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/su
Nov 14 13:14:42 laptop-mmi sudo[8060]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 14 13:14:42 laptop-mmi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
-- Subject: Unit network.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit network.service has begun starting up.
Nov 14 13:14:42 laptop-mmi NetworkManager[901]: <info>  [1510683282.8342] ifcfg-rh: update /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Auto_MMIWIFI (841f490b-2177-4d4b-b38f-68910762f932,"Auto MMIWIFI")
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi network[8078]: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi network[8078]: Bringing up interface Auto_KMitnick_5Ghz:  [  OK  ]
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi network[8078]: Bringing up interface Auto_MMIWIFI:  [  OK  ]
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi network[8078]: Bringing up interface Auto_MMIWIFI-Guest:  [  OK  ]
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi NetworkManager[901]: <info>  [1510683283.1789] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="52089632-ee7b-3193-9582-51b7f651bc0a" name="enp3s0" result="fail" reason="No suitable device found 
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi network[8078]: Bringing up interface enp3s0:  Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi network[8078]: [FAILED]
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi systemd[1]: network.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
-- Subject: Unit network.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit network.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=network comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi systemd[1]: network.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi systemd[1]: network.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi audit[8060]: USER_END pid=8060 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=3 msg='op=PAM:session_close grantors=pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd,pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sud
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi audit[8060]: CRED_DISP pid=8060 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=3 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_unix acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
Nov 14 13:14:43 laptop-mmi sudo[8060]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

What is killing my wired network or why is being kill?

Note: if you need something else feel free to ask

Comment: If you run `ifconfig -a`, is the name of the network there the same one referred to in the log?